# Does the android opengl Matrix class use the GPU in its calculations?

Tags: java, android, performance, opengl-es, matrix-multiplication

If it does, what would be the best way to use it?

Am I right in assuming it would be best to, if I use it, use it as often (within reason) as possible to saturate the GPU?

If it doesn't what would be an easy way to do a lot of matrix multiplications really fast? I am working in Android Studio with Java.

Comment: If you are willing to just target ARM you could look into using NEON vectorized instructions via the NDK/JNI https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/cpu-arm-neon.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Operations on just a single set of 4×4 matrices do not really benefit from GPU acceleration. That is for four reasons:

1. There's a certain overhead associated with submitting work tasks to the GPU.
2. Although GPUs are connected via high bandwidth interconnects, the I/O bandwidth from/to a GPU usually is still an order of magnitude below CPU memory bandwidth.
3. A single set of 4×4 matrices easily fits into L1 cache.
4. Modern CPUs have vector instructions, which essentially crunch whole 4×4 matrices as a whole.

> If it doesn't what would be an easy way to do a lot of matrix multiplications really fast?

That actually depends on the kind of data: What's the population distribution of your matrices? How much exchange happens between sets of matrices? Are your matrix accesses dominated by gather-read or scatter-writes?

There are a number of pathological cases where single thread CPU performance actually beats GPUs.

Comment: If I would have enough 4x4 matrix multiplications, would that overcome the overhead associated with moving it all to the GPU? Or are these matrices just way too small?

Comment: @FelixBrakel: The break even threshold really depends on the plattform. However typical execution setup time is on the order of about 1µs. So anything you can be done on the CPU in under, lets say <100ns simply is not worth the effort to launch on a GPU.